# matplotlib plot and its mpld3 version have different markers sizes

Tags: python, matplotlib, mpld3

I have this minimum reproducible code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import mpld3

# Create a DataFrame with columns id, X, and Y
# num_points = 100
# t = np.linspace(0, 4 * np.pi, num_points)
# data = {'id': range(1, num_points + 1), 'X': 10 * np.cos(t), 'Y': 5 * np.sin(t)}  # Adjust amplitude and frequency as needed
# df = pd.DataFrame(data)

num_points = 25000
t = np.linspace(0, 8 * np.pi, num_points)  # Adjust the range to control the length of the trajectory
data = {'id': range(1, num_points + 1), 'X': 10 * np.cos(t), 'Y': 5 * np.sin(t)}  # Adjust amplitude and frequency as needed
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# Set linewidth and markersize
linewidth = 0.1
markersize = 2

# Plot the trajectory with modified parameters
plt.plot(df['X'], df['Y'], marker='.', linestyle='-', linewidth=linewidth, markersize=markersize)
plt.title('Trajectory Plot')
plt.xlabel('X Coordinates')
plt.ylabel('Y Coordinates')

# Convert the plot to HTML using mpld3
html_fig = mpld3.fig_to_html(plt.gcf())

# Generate a simple HTML template
html_template = f"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Trajectory Plot</title>
  
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Trajectory Plot</h1>
  {html_fig}
</body>
</html>
"""

# <script src="https://mpld3.github.io/js/mpld3.v0.5.2.js"></script>

# Save the HTML to a file
with open('trajectory_plot.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html_template)

# Display the Matplotlib plot
plt.show()
```

With this I get two things:

1. A html page `trajectory_plot.html` with an interactive plot in it
2. The plot itself

Now observe the plot
[image]
They are very similar.

However if you zoom the plots they differ very much in the marker size

In the plot it self:
[image]

In the embedded plot
[image]

Why is this and how can I correct it?

Comment: The implementation of the line widths in matplotlib is not always consistent. What you have observed is probably the inconsistency between two different backends. I guess you cannot change it except after plotting (you can adjust the linewidth dynamically, given the new ranges on the x and y axes).

Comment: @YuliaV Thanks. I just read this https://mpld3.github.io/faq.html . Apparently mpld3 can not be used for large datasets :(

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to show a static picture on a web page?

Comment: @YuliaV What I was trying to achieve (and drop already) is to show a dynamic matplotlib plot on a web page. (Well many of them). Apparently this is not possible with my dataset and it is also very heavy. My next target now is to show a static picture of plots on a web page and for that I will use BytesIO and base64

Comment: There is a replit.com - an online Python IDE - that has an iframe option. I.e. you would put your code (or just data + plotting code) on replit, and then the iframe with your replit project on your web page. This option doesn't have data limitations. It's free, for now at least. I have not tried it for a while; if you do, could you let me know how it worked?  https://docs.replit.com/hosting/embedding-repls